# How to Set Sensor Data Parameters?

Tags: sensors, data, constants

Good day! How to set sensor Data parameters?

Like the data only set for example it starts with minimum value of 3 and ends with maximum value of 6 and it will turn on led 1 and if minimum value of 1 and maximum value of 2 turn on led 2 just like that?

My actual code for that:

```
float basa = scale.get_units();
if( basa >= 4 )
{ 
  digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
}
else if( basa >= 2 )
{ 
  digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
}
```

This code shows that if ever it reaches value of 4 the value of 2 will react also so my question is how set sensor data value like it will only react Value1 - Value2 like that.

thank you

Comment: 2 will not react

Comment: I don't understand, what your problem is. Please describe it more

Comment: Do you really see, that both LEDs get turned on, when `basa >= 4`? The logic of your if statements seems to be correct. If `basa >= 4`, the first condition will execute and LED1 will be turned on. The second condition will not execute, because it is in an else statement, where the if statement already evaluated true. Do you reset the LEDs somewhere else in your code? If not, you might see, that the values from your scale simply go up and pass both intervals. If only the first measurement is in the interval between 2 and 4, and the second is over 4, the code will light up both LEDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
float basa = scale.get_units();

digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
digitalWrite(led2, LOW);

if( basa >= 2 && basa < 4 )
{ 
  digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
}

if( basa >= 4 )
{ 
  digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
}
```

**EDIT: as suggested by @chrisl (see comments)**

If understand you problem correctly, you try to light up 2 LEDs according to the value you read from a scale. IMHO you want to assign three intervals (ranges) like so:

```
(-INF, 2) : none of the LEDs is switched on
[2, 4)    : only LED 2 is switched on
[4, +INF) : only LED 1 is switched on
```

- `[x` or `x]` means the x belongs to the interval.
- `(x` or `x)` means the x does not belong to the interval.
- `+INF` and `-INF` are the positive or negative infinity.

My code does the following:

I use the observation, that the intervals do not intersect and the union of the intervals are the complete real number space. (Although your scale has a more narrow range: (0-?kg). The program can handle a wider range compared to the the scale, so it is not a problem.)

If the first condition `(-INF, 2)` is `true`, none of the others would be and we can be sure that the LEDs I switched off with the `digitalWrite(ledX, LOW);`
 statements will stay off. If the value is in the range of `[2, 4)` I switch on LED2 and can be sure that the other LED stays off because the condition `basa >= 4` can not be `true`. And if the value is in the range of  `[4, +INF)` I switch on LED1 and can be sure that LED 2 has not been switched on because the condition `basa >= 2 && basa < 4` can not be `true`.

Comment: I would say this does exactly the same as the OPs code, except for the `digitalWrite(ledX, LOW)` calls. Please explain more how this solves the OPs problem (whatever that problem actually is)

Comment: @chrisl OP wants when value is 2 turn on an LED and when it's 4 another. but in OP code when it's 4, 2 condition also applies. so Peter approach is correct. if it's bigger than 2 and less than 4 is what OP exactly wants.

Comment: @chrisl You're right, I should have explained the solution, but it was late last evening ;-). I'll edit the answer and add my understanding of the problem also. Btw, my code differs not only in the `digitalWrite(ledX, LOW)` statements. I removed the else and so I decoupled the two cases and I used a range [2,4) for the first case. The < 2 case is implicitly handled by the `digitalWrite(ledX, LOW)` statements.

Comment: @ElectronSurf No, in the OPs code, when `basa >= 4` only the first condition applies and thus only led1 is turned on. The second condition is not executed in that case, because it is in an `else` statement. The code only comes to that condition, when `basa < 4`. Peter Paul Kiefer added the case for `basa < 2` and decoupled the if statements (which could be seen as an improvement).

Comment: @chrisl "if ever it reaches value of 4 the value of 2 will react" what I said was based on OP explanation.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer, you missed the 'else' in OP's snippet?

Comment: @Juraj I did not missed the `else`; I removed it. For me it was one of the means to achieve what I thought the OP had asked for. Have I interpreted the OPs question right? Only the OP can told us. But I fear he stopped the collaboration ;-).

Comment: thanks pal appreciated it